# Excluding elements of a vector from another vector, not using setdiff

Tags: r

I have a character vector, and I want to exclude elements from it which are present in a second vector. I don't know how to work the negation in this case while still considering the entire vector

```
vector[vector ! %in% vector2]
```

I can obviously do `vector[vector != single_character]` but that only works for a single character.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're close

```
vector[!vector %in% vector2]
```

or, even though you said "not using setdiff"

```
setdiff(vector, vector2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector1 <- letters[1:4]
set.seed(001)
vector2 <- sample(letters[1:15], 10, replace=TRUE)

 vector1
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
vector2
 [1] "d" "f" "i" "n" "d" "n" "o" "j" "j" "a"

vector2 [!(vector2 %in% vector1)] # elements in vector2 that are not in vector1
[1] "f" "i" "n" "n" "o" "j" "j"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new operator,

```
 `%ni%` = Negate(`%in%`)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution is available now:

```
library(textclean)
# master character vector
vector1 = c("blue", "green", "red")
# vector containing elements to be removed from master vector
vector2 = c("green", "red")
drop_element_fixed(vector1, vector2)

# Output:
# [1] "blue"
```