# conditional removing from a vector without if statement in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, if-statement, vector

Without using an `if` statement, is it possible to remove `"out"` from a vector of characters (e.g., `a1`) and if `"out"` doesn't exist in the vector (e.g., `a2`) just return the vector itself?

```
a1 = c("out", "bagh", "bir")
a2 = c("bagh", "bir")

 a1[-which("out" %in% a1)]

 a2[-which("out" %in% a2)]
```

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12628104/5325862

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setdiff`

```
setdiff(a1, "out")
#[1] "bagh" "bir" 

setdiff(a2, "out")
#[1] "bagh" "bir"
```

---

`%in%` would work as well if we don't use `which`

```
a1[!a1 %in% "out"]
a2[!a2 %in% "out"]
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423294/removing-special-suffixes-from-inside-a-list-in-r) have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

And also very R-ish:

`a1[a1 != "out"]`

Select all vector elements which are unequal to "out".