# removing suffixes from variable names inside a list in R

Tags: r, regex, list, function, dataframe

Using BASE R, I was wondering how I can remove  `..number` suffixes from variables (e.g., `short..3` becomes `short`) in `G` below?

```
G <- list(AA = list(short..3 = data.frame(dint = 5:7, SD = 0:2), 
                    short..2 = NULL, 
                    del1 = data.frame(dint = 1:3, SD = 2:4), 
                    del1..2 = NULL, del2 = NULL), 
          BB = list(short = data.frame(dint = 1:4, SD = 2:5), 
                    short..2 = NULL, 
                    del1..4 = data.frame(dint = 5:6, SD = 3:4), 
                    del1..2 = NULL, 
                    del2 = data.frame(dint = 6, SD = 1)))
```

Comment: probably appropriate use of `gsub()`. Are you going to have duplicate names if you remove all of the suffixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i in seq_along(G)) {
  names(G[[i]]) <- gsub("(.*)\\.\\.\\d*", "\\1", names(G[[i]]))
}
```

OR

```
lapply(G, function(i) setNames(i, gsub("(.*)\\.\\.\\d*", "\\1", names(i))))
```

Comment: And if your `number` (in `..number`) is only a one digit integer (as in your example), you don't need the `*` after `\\d`