# Modify a list by deleting elements based on a condition

Tags: r, vector, subset

I have to make a function that receives a list of x elements and modify it by deleting elements that are 2 or 7.

Here's my resolution to that problem:

```
extract.inputs <- function(x) { for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if(x[i] == 2 | x[i] == 7){
     x[x != i]}}}
```

When I try to pass

```
lst <- c(2, 2, -3, 1, -99, -10, 10, 7)
```

as a parameter, it does not modify the list, it returns the exact same list

How do I modify it so I can get a list without 2 and 7 numbers?

Comment: I changed the name of your _vector_ to `lst` because `list` is a function name.

Comment: You can try `lst[!(lst %in% c(2, 7))]` or `setdiff(lst, c(2, 7))`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Excluding elements of a vector from another vector, not using setdiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628104/excluding-elements-of-a-vector-from-another-vector-not-using-setdiff)

Comment: If you want to modify an existing list by removing elements (you are showing a vector here), you could set those elements to NULL, e.g. something like this: `set.seed(123); l <- as.list(sample(1:20, 100, replace=T)); l[l==2|l==7] <- NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the previous advice, note that the `which` function can be used to generate the positions of values in a vector that you want.  So:

```
vals <- which(lst !=2 & lst !=7)
vals
[1] 3 4 5 6 7
lst[vals]
[1]  -3   1 -99 -10  10

# You can combine both statements
lst[which(lst !=2 & lst !=7)]
[1]  -3   1 -99 -10  10
```

`which` is a very handy function generally.